# Chromedriver session not created

Tags: automation, selenium-chromedriver

My test environment was recently updated to Chrome 94. I've configured automation to use the available 94 version of chromedriver. All scripts are failing, due to the chromedriver session:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.54)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=94.0.4606.61
```

I've noted this occurring in the past, but have never found a satisfactory fix. Why are they out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue. We initially had the same issue after the chrome upgrade while our Robot scripts were triggered by windows task scheduler. Later, we installed another task scheduler called "System Scheduler" and when the robot batch files were triggered from there, we had no issues. So, am wondering if the issue is from a task scheduler access related concerns.
Ideally saying, haven't seen any solution for this yet!

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the GPU, while initializing chrome driver

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks Jayanth. This is part of the solution I used the other day. I'd need point out that this isn't actually sufficient. In order to not have all tests run headlessly at a fixed resolution, it is also necessary to explicitly use the --headless argument and state the resolution also.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do following, in Python:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
```

because disabling gpu alone always ran tests with no visible browser, but screenshots from tests were showing a smaller fixed window size (which couldn't be altered in test)